# Send and Receive message to/from JBoss JMS Queue on WebSphere

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I have 2 requirements;

1. I want to send message from an application which would be running on
   WebSphere to a Queue which is hosted on JBoss.
2. Receive a message on Spring JMS listener (or MDB not decided yet)
   which would be running
       on WebSphere from a Queue which is Hosted on JBoss.

Could anyone please give me any pointer on this remote communication?

Do I need JBoss client Jars at my WebShpere?

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason, why you are not using websphere JMS?

Comment: Well I am doing changes in existing application which is running on WebSphere but I do need to communicate to ThunderHead System via JMS which is using JBoss as Application server. Both the applications are running independently...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that and of course you would need JBoss MQ jars in order to connect to Jboss MQ. You do not need to put them in websphere, rather you could bundle them with the application war.

Edit 1: (How to setup external JMS provider in websphere - An example with Active MQ)

Please see the below link for steps to do that; similar steps to be performed for Jboss as well.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/timdp/entry/using_activemq_as_a_jms_provider_in_websphere_application_server_7149?lang=en

Comment: the code what i am trying...

Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://jboss.host.name:1099");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext( env);
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup( "jms/JBossJMSConnectionFactory" );

but i am getting connection factory as Null.
Any clue? (i added jboss-client jars in my application war)

Comment: Why not, you are using Websphere console to define an external JMS provider? Have added an example link in the post.

Comment: Ohh No...Do i need to setup the external JMS provider? I am googling to know how to setup external jms provider but request you to please specify all required steps which i need to follow for this. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry!!! i didn't see full response from you. You have given link as well for steps...i am check that..